# How to validate a text field with regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I want to validate a textfield which is started with number or alphabets but not any special symbol like (! @ # etc.) through regular expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like this `^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9@#$%^&*]*` this allow string starting with `a-zA-Z0-9` and  the characters given in second bracket

Answer (score 0):

```
^[0-9A-Za-z]
```

Answer (score 0):

`\w` represents a word character: `[a-zA-Z_0-9]`